# Webstorm code analysis failing in a handlebars template script tag?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, webstorm

I am writing a .hbs file in Webstorm 8. It looks similar to the code below.

```
<!-- some html -->
<script type="text/javascript">    
var {{name}} = '{{value}}';
</script>
```

WS marks the code as erroneous: "Expected new line or semicolon", "Variable name expected"

Is it that I am doing something wrong or is it a limitation in the WS handlebars inspector? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
var {{name}} = '{{value}}';
</script>
```

Comment: I want the resulting html to have a js code script tag inside. Let's say, name is Diego and value is 8. I want the result to be <script src="text/javascript">    
var Diego = '8';
</script>
If the result was 
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
var Diego = '8';
</script>
The js code would never be executed and variable 'Diego' would never be assigned with value 8.

Comment: In other words, my template is not the content of the script tag. The whole file is the template and it contains a js script tag.

Comment: I see. But WebStorm uses the 'type' attribute of the script tag when injecting language into it. So it treats the content of your script tag as javascript, reporting syntax errors. BTW, src="text/javascript" is not a correct syntax anyway, it should be type="text/javascript"